# Selenium module's webdriver.Firefox() not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I will provide my code, with included error message. I believe I need to move the gecko driver to PATH, but I tried to do some research on how to do this and unfortunately I didn't find anything definitive. I'm hoping that someone could give me a hand.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\lukep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\lukep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\lukep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\lukep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```